# How do i nicely decode Laravel failed jobs JSON

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5

How should i decode and "prettify" Laravel`s failed-jobs payload?

In my DB in table failed_jobs i have column payload that reads like this:

```
{"job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","data":{"commandName":"App\\Jobs\\createHostingOncPanel","command":"O:30:\"App\\Jobs\\createHostingOncPanel\":7:{s:10:\"\u0000*\u0000orderNo\";i:11;s:18:\"\u0000*\u0000hostingPackages\";s:45:\"[{\"domainName\":\"qwddqwd.io\",\"hostingType\":1}]\";s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000user\";O:45:\"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier\":2:{s:5:\"class\";s:8:\"App\\User\";s:2:\"id\";i:1;}s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000job\";N;}"}}
```

Would like to get the string json decoded into something readable.

What kind of format is this? :)

PS: This is a Laravel 5.2 version

Comment: you already said what format it is: json. so use json_decode()... and within that json, there appears to be a php serialize() data structure,which will itself have to be unserialized()

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Read from failed_jobs table

json_decode the payload from failed_jobs table

```
$jsonpayload = json_decode($payload);
```

unserialize the payload command

```
$data = unserialize($jsonpayload->data->command);
print_r($data);//This is the data passed to queue
```

Comment: This should definitely be in the Laravel documentation! Thank you sir, very valuable info

Comment: @MikeHarrison I know this is "old" but this is not a correct answer, I mean, this works, but that does not mean it is the best one... @Jeff replied with a correct and best answer, you handle the exception at the moment, not later to be decoded, or if you want to do that, you store something new in your database, you do not use `unserialize`, `json_decode`, etc anymore in Laravel... If you have to use some of those functions in a plain Laravel (not package), then it means you are using it or doing something wrong... You avoid vanilla PHP 100%...

Comment: @matiaslauriti I didn't post the answer...however I will say sometimes it is important to know how to interact with failed jobs after they happen so this answer is still useful

Comment: I agree with your last statement, but I do not agree this is the way. You have a special section dedicated to this on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#cleaning-up-after-failed-jobs). You do not `unserialize` anything, you handle it at the moment. Create a new model or anything that will help you track the failed job, but you do not `unserialize` it and do stuff with it... What you are suggesting is similar to continue using `$_POST` or any similar when you should use the `request`... this is a framework and handles everything... no need to do this cavern stuff...

Answer (score 5):

I too was having problem as I did not had direct access to production database.
I created a route with auth and my controller returned json with all the failed jobs formatted. Here is controller code. With this I was also able to get formatted stack trace of exception due to which job failed

```
    public function getFailedJob()
    {
        #Fetch all the failed jobs
        $jobs = DB::table('failed_jobs')->select()->get();

        #Loop through all the failed jobs and format them for json printing
        foreach ($jobs as $job) {
            $jsonpayload = json_decode($job->payload);
            $job->payload = $jsonpayload;

            $jsonpayload->data->command = unserialize($jsonpayload->data->command);
            $job->exception  = explode("\n", $job->exception);
        }

        return response()->json($jobs);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend handling the event as-it-happens and then storing any data you need in your own way.  You can use Failed Job Events to capture all failed jobs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#failed-job-events

Or you can use the `failed()` function on the job itself: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs

Otherwise, Marc's comment seems to make sense to me.

Comment: I have try'd to intercept the failing job from AppServiceProvider.

Comment: damn enter :)

Still get this string : string(320) "O:30:"App\Jobs\createHostingOncPanel":7:{s:10:"\000*\000orderNo";i:18;s:18:"\000*\000hostingPackages";s:47:"[{"domainName":"fireman21.nu","hostingType":3}]";s:7:"\000*\000user";O:45:"Illuminate\Contracts\Database\ModelIdentifier":2:{s:5:"class"
;s:8:"App\User";s:2:"id";i:1;}s:10:"connection";N;s:5:"queue";N;s:5:"delay";N;s:6:"\000*\000job";N;}"

Have also given json_decode and unserialize a go, with no luck

Answer (score 2):

I do a gree that it's better to handle job as it fails. But if you want a lazy, stubborn workaround, you can do this. The problem with `unserialize` is that it hides protected attributes, but public attributes are returned as `null`.

Create a trait `ExposeJobComands`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait ExposeJobComands {

    public function getAllVars()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

Make all jobs use this trait.
Create a custom cast `Payload`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Casts;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;
class Payload implements CastsAttributes
{
    public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        $payload = json_decode($value);
        $command = unserialize($payload->data->command);
        $payload->data->command = $command->getAllVars();

        return $payload;
    }
}
```

Create a model for failed jobs and cast payload to `Payload::class`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Casts\Payload;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FailedJob extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'payload' => Payload::class,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$j = App\Models\Jobs::select('payload')->get();
$aw = json_decode($j[0]->payload)->data->command;
$cm = unserialize($aw);
dd($cm->payload);
```